# Yesod Type Error - AuthId master vs. Key User

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a Yesod application. My current goal is to have the application use a email / password for authentication. However, I am running into a type error.

I believe I am following the directions in the [Yesod Book](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/authentication-and-authorization) properly. This is my current [code for Foundation.hs](https://lpaste.net/5865328122487898112).

The error is as follows:

```
• Could not deduce: m ~ HandlerFor site0
  from the context: (MonadHandler m, HandlerSite m ~ master)
    bound by the type signature for:
              getAuthId :: forall (m :: * -> *) master.
                            (MonadHandler m, HandlerSite m ~ master) =>
                            Creds master -> m (Maybe (AuthId master))
    at src/Foundation.hs:206:18-102
  ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      getAuthId :: forall (m :: * -> *) master.
                  (MonadHandler m, HandlerSite m ~ master) =>
                  Creds master -> m (Maybe (AuthId master))
    at src/Foundation.hs:206:18-102
  Expected type: m (Maybe (AuthId master))
    Actual type: HandlerFor site0 (Maybe (Key User))
• In the expression:
    runDB
      $ do x <- insertBy $ User (credsIdent creds) Nothing Nothing False
          return
            $ Just
                $ case x of
                    Left (Entity userid _) -> userid
                    Right userid -> userid
  In an equation for ‘getAuthId’:
      getAuthId creds
        = runDB
            $ do x <- insertBy $ User (credsIdent creds) Nothing Nothing False
                return
                  $ Just
                      $ case x of
                          Left (Entity userid _) -> userid
                          Right userid -> userid
  In the instance declaration for ‘YesodAuth App’
• Relevant bindings include
    getAuthId :: Creds master -> m (Maybe (AuthId master))
      (bound at src/Foundation.hs:207:5)
|
|     getAuthId creds = runDB $ do
|                       ^^^^^^^^^^...
```

The part that I am focusing on is:

```
Expected type: m (Maybe (AuthId master))
Actual type: HandlerFor site0 (Maybe (Key User))
```

Here is what I (think) I know:

- m ~ HandlerFor site0
- type AuthId App = UserId
- type UserId = Key User

Note: I have assumed that Template Haskell has generated the type alias `type UserId = Key User` based on [Persistent chapter of the Yesod Book](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) (search for `PersonId` on that page) and the fact that my models file contains the following:

```
-- By default this file is used by `persistFileWith` in Model.hs (which is imported by Foundation.hs)
-- Syntax for this file here: https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/master/docs/Persistent-entity-syntax.md

User
    email Text
    password Text Maybe
    verkey Text Maybe
    verified Bool
    UniqueUser email
    deriving Typeable
```

If I make all these substitutions, the conclusion that I come to is that expected type is `m (Maybe (AuthId master))`, which is equivalent to `m (Maybe UserId)`, which is equivalent to `m (Maybe (Key User))`. For the actual type, `HandlerFor site0 (Maybe (Key User))` is equivalent to `m (Maybe (Key User))`. It seems to me that the expected and actual types are the same, but the compiler is not coming to that same conclusion.

I was wondering what I need to do here to address the issue that the compiler is having.

P.S. I originally posted this question on Reddit. Normally I don't post to two different places, but this is blocking me from proceeding further.

Comment: Have you tried removing the type signature of getAuthId ?

Comment: I marked it as duplicate, as you suggseted. If you found the answer (in the duplicated post) you can answer and accept your own answer saying it's over and maybe write a small summary of the accepted answer.